# HTML isn't recognizing the JS file in the same folder

Tags: javascript, html

I have some basic html below, and for some reason it's not recognizing the js file I linked in the script tag. Am I linking it incorrectly in some way?:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/index.css">
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board">
      <svg id="svg"></svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the respective index.js:

```
const grid = [
   [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
   [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
   [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
   [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
   [{},{},{},{color: "red"},{color:"black"},{},{}],
];

const render = () =>{
   console.info("rendering?")
   const svg = document.getElementById("svg");
   let doc = ``;
   for (var i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
      var row = grid[i];
      for (var j=0; j<row.length; j++){
         const square = grid[i][j];
         const color = square && square.color || 'gray';
         doc = doc + `<circle onclick="clickSquare(${i}, ${j})" fill = '${color}' r='30px' cx='${j * 70 + 50}px' cy='${i * 70 + 50}px'> </circle>`;
      }
   }
   svg.innerHTML = doc;
}

window.clickSquare = (x, y) => {
   console.log("You clicked square ", x, y);
}
```

Comment: Are you opening the HTML file from your drive directly or is it hosted by a web server? The leading slash in `/index.js` could be the problem.

Comment: If the files are side by side the no need for the slash, if they are in folders then include the folder path but no leading slashes are necessary

Comment: do you working on unix server? access rights are ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the / before it.  Call render in your script and move it to the bottom of the dom.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board">
      <svg id="svg"></svg>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS Below

```
const grid = [
   [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
   [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
   [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
   [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
   [{},{},{},{color: "red"},{color:"black"},{},{}],
];

const render = () =>{
   console.info("rendering?")
   const svg = document.getElementById("svg");
   let doc = ``;
   for (var i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
      var row = grid[i];
      for (var j=0; j<row.length; j++){
         const square = grid[i][j];
         const color = square && square.color || 'gray';
         doc = doc + `<circle onclick="clickSquare(${i}, ${j})" fill = '${color}' r='30px' cx='${j * 70 + 50}px' cy='${i * 70 + 50}px'> </circle>`;
      }
   }
   svg.innerHTML = doc;
}

render()

window.clickSquare = (x, y) => {
   console.log("You clicked square ", x, y);
}
```

Comment: he says "it's not recognizing the js file", css should be loaded ok and it's in the same folder.

Comment: That's not how file systems work.  The slash is not needed in either case.  Also he's not using href he's using src on the css link and THAT IS WRONG.

Comment: Just made this fix and it doesn't seem to have changed anything. It's recognizing the CSS just fine, but not the js. I've edited my post to include the js in case the issue is there.

Comment: There is nothing calling the "render()" function and therefore it will do nothing.  When I add render() on line 24 I get a syntax error, but the function does start to load.

Comment: of course it won't render anything because you're calling the javascript before the dom has finished loading

Comment: I have made changes that make it so this now works.

Comment: what I don't understand is why you made "render()"  a constant and not just a function.

Answer (score 1):

First remove the `/` *(slash)* before the filename,

and also when you link a `java-script` file add the `type` as `application/javascript` when it put it recognize the file type is `java-script`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="index.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </head>

</html>
```